# Passing component name to title field in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue app like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <Navbar/>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
  <Foot/>
</div>
```

As I change pages via router-links, I'd like to also update the {{title}} field. The hacky way I've done it is this:

```
methods: {
 logRoute() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.title = this.$route.name
  });
 }
}
```

However, sometimes I'd like to have the title be something different according to a property in the component, for example the "About" page is titled "About me." What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Jasper try this way.

Go to your route and and a meta on the router you want to have a title on like the code below

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  },
]
```

And go to your App.vue and add this a watch to look up when you go to different pages if you dont have a meta with a title it will put a default value on the website title.

```
export default {
  watch: {
    '$route' (to) {
      document.title = to.meta.title || 'Default Title'
    }
  },
};
```

I hope this solves your problem have a nice day !

Comment: Thank you very much! That got me where I wanted to go.

Comment: Glad to help you out have a nice day :) !